# Dropdown-Menu - Columns Stacking Inside

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-5, grid-layout

Trying to create a filter on a web page that utilizes Bootstrap's drop-down menu and places each filter in columns side-by-side, but instead it stacks them right now. The filter menu is created dynamically by looping through an array of items I want to create and each item is a new column I want to place on my menu. I was trying to utilize the grid layout (container > row > column) with the class row-cols-# on my row element but that does not work as I thought it would.

I can force my menu to be a certain width using the `style` property and make the columns position correctly, but then my menu is no longer sizing appropriately based on n columns.

I am utilizing d-flex, flex-row and flex-column to create my sidebar navigation and  and I am wondering if that is causing some of the issues?

Here is a sample of webpage stripped-down to illustrate. [Filter Menu Help](https://codeply.com/v/957ai6U6Fu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason they're stacking is because you're using `.col-auto` while `.row` by default has `flex-wrap: wrap;`, so it will keep each column as small as possible and wrap them.

The second reason is that the `dropdown-menu` is positioned absolutely but relatively to the `.dropdown` wrapper. Because you positioned the wrapper on the right side of the page, the `dropdown-menu` won't grow in width as you would expect.

So:

- Don't use auto columns but rather set a `max-width` on the `dropdown-menu`.
- Remove the `<div class="dropdown"></div>` wrapper.

##### Here's an example how you could make your dropdown in Codeply using your layout.

On small screen sizes the columns will stack using `<div class="row flex-column flex-sm-row">`. Each filter column utilizes a list `<ul><li>...</li></ul>` to contain the check-boxes and for easy styling.

```
<form class="dropdown-menu p-2 mt-1 overflow-auto">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row flex-column flex-sm-row">
      <ul class="col list-unstyled">
        <li>
          <h6 class="dropdown-header">Dropdown header</h6>
          <hr class="dropdown-divider">
        </li>
        <li>
          <input class="form-check-input me-1" type="checkbox" value="" id="first">
          <label class="form-check-label stretched-link" for="first">First checkbox</label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input class="form-check-input me-1" type="checkbox" value="" id="second">
          <label class="form-check-label stretched-link" for="second">Second checkbox</label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input class="form-check-input me-1" type="checkbox" value="" id="third">
          <label class="form-check-label stretched-link" for="third">Third checkbox</label>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="col list-unstyled">
        ...
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-end gap-3">
      <button type="reset" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning clear-filter">Clear Filter</button>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

To tell Flex when to start wrapping the columns, set a `max-width` on the `dropdown-menu`. For the example I set it to `75vw` but it can by any width you want. *You can use `row-cols-*` instead, but you will have to add a column number for every break point, like `.row-cols-1 row-cols-sm-2 row-cols-md-4` whereas setting a `max-width` is just easier to maintain and looks better visually with how the columns will stretch.*

For the `stretched-link` to work [the parent must have `position: relative;` applied to it.](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/helpers/stretched-link/) And `whitespace: nowrap;` is used to keep each `<label>` in-line with the checkbox.

```
form {
 max-width: 75vw;
 max-height: 80vh;
}

.col li {
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Lastly, to prevent the `dropdown-menu` from closing when interacting with it add [`data-bs-auto-close="outside"` on the `<button>` toggler.](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/dropdowns/#auto-close-behavior)

Comment: This resolved my CSS issues! Thank you so much! I will need to make sure I utilizing the different screen size options.

One last question though, if I wanted to add a scroll-bar to my columns (i.e. maybe have 20 filters for one column), what would be your suggestion? `overflow-y-scoll` ? I tried that and I seem to get a horizontal scroll with it.

Comment: @Franklin Don't use `overflow: auto` on columns, it will give you all kinds of issues. Rather change the layout a bit (not making the column part of the `<ul>` but only the checkboxes) and set a `max-height` on the checkbox list. [Here's the example](https://www.codeply.com/v/mOcRCw4AUH). The reason for the horizontal scrollbar on the column is because the scrollbar is a not part of its contents and thus ignored when its width is calculated in Flexbox, so they're 'forced' in, causing the `<label>` to overflow. When a scrollbar appears as a child element of a column, its width is accounted for.